# Should an implementation of IEqualityComparer.Equals allow null values?

Tags: c#, generics, equality

I have a custom generic data structure that includes a Find method:

```
public bool Find(TValue value, IEqualityComparer<TValue> comparer)
{
    foreach (var x in items)
    {
        if (comparer.Equals(value, x))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I got a report recently from a client who said that it causes his equality comparer to throw `NullReferenceException` if `value` is `null` or if one of the items in the collection is `null`.

My initial response was that his `IEqualityComparer<T>.Equals` implementation was in error because it doesn't deal gracefully with `null` values. But I haven't been able to find any documentation to explicitly back me up. I have some evidence to indicate that I'm right, but nothing explicit.

First, it seems silly that I'd have change that simple call to `comparer.Equals` to:

```
if (x == null)
{
    if (value == null)
        return true;
}
else if (value != null && comparer.Equals(value, x))
    return true;
```

Second, the documentation for [Object.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) says, among other things:

- `x.Equals(null)` returns `false`.
- Implementations of `Equals` must not throw exceptions.

That, to me, is strong evidence that [IEqualityComparer<T>.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132154.aspx) should gracefully handle null parameters.

Other evidence is that the documentation for [IComparer.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh5ks3b3.aspx) says:

> Comparing null with any reference type is allowed and does not
>   generate an exception. A null reference is considered to be less than
>   any reference that is not null.

One would expect `IEqualityComparer<T>.Equals` to act similarly. It's amusing to note, though, that the example given on that page will throw `NullReferenceException` if either parameter is `null`.

I've been through the documentation for `Object.Equals`, `IEquatable<T>`, `IEqualityComparer<T>`, and `IEqualityComparer`, and countless blog posts, articles, and SO questions. Nothing gives any specific guidelines about how to handle `null` parameters.

Do such guidelines exist? If not, what do the gurus recommend, and why?

Comment: I suspect that the documentation doesn't specify the handling of nulls because the meaning of a null value could be dependent on type or context.  I didn't see anything in the non-generic IEqualtyComparer.Equals(object, object) documentation, either.  The point of creating a custom implementation of the interface is to allow a developer to implement logic appropriate to the type and the context at hand.  In this case, the client is working in a context where some references are null, so it is the client's responsibility for the custom logic to handle that situation.

Comment: @phoog: But that would be inconsistent with the behavior of `IComparer.Compare(object, object)`, which *does* specify the handling of nulls. Well, at least alludes very strongly to it. And, as was pointed out, `Object.Equals(object, object)` and `Object.Equals(object)` are quite specific about it.

Comment: You're right, it is inconsistent.  It's also inconsistent with `IComparer<T>.Compare`.  The "remarks" sections of both methods' documentation specify the handling of null references, while as you found, documentation for Equals(x,y) methods does not.  It seems entirely possible that the omission is an oversight, in which case, the client's implementation is in error.  If the omission is not an oversight, though, the client's implementation is still in error, for the reason outlined in my previous comment.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The closest method in the .NET framework itself after which all `IEqualityComparer.Equals` methods should be modeled is the static [`Object.Equals(object,object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx) method. According to the documentation, this method handles `null`s gracefully. I think that this provides enough indication on the intent of the .NET designers: `IEqualityComparer.Equals` should handle nulls as well, and it should handle them in a similar way (i.e. treating two `null`s as equal to each other).

Comment: Missed that one when looking at documentation. Thank you. That answers my question perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

The guidelines that FxCop uses, includes a stipulation that every public method of a public type must handle null arguments, such as by throwing `ArgumentNullException`. In your case, given the `Object.Equals` you noted, then you just need to do the null test and return false - because only null is equal to null :)

This is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182182(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Yes, I agree that public methods should check their types. But that doesn't really answer my question. Should `x.Compare(null, null)` (assuming `x` implements `IEqualityComparer<T>`) return 0? Or should it throw an exception?

Comment: argh. I meant `x.Equals(null, null)`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the `EqualityComparer<T>` abstract base class (not the interface, but does implement it) has some comments on its `Equals` methods.

For `EqualityComparer<T>.Equals(T, T)` the MSDN doesn't state any known exceptions are typically thrown (and the MSDN is usually pretty good about listing exceptions). Certainly passing in any class (custom or BCL) and comparing it to `null` doesn't throw any exceptions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132154.aspx

Answer (score 2):

A value of `null` should be regarded as any other value.  If you are asked whether the contents of two boxes should be considered identical, the question is perfectly valid even if one or both of the boxes is empty.  If both boxes are empty, their (non-)contents are equal.  If one is empty and the other isn't, then they're clearly not totally equivalent, and probably wouldn't compare equal, but there are cases where they legitimately could.

The default equivalence relation defined by `Object.Equals(Object)` and `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T)` (the latter, if defined, should use the same relation as the former) should only regard things as equal if they're equivalent in essentially every way, and by that definition, no non-null object can be considered equivalent to null (since `null` would have no means of comparing itself to a non-null object).  On the other hand, it is entirely normal for an `IEqualityComparer<T>` to define two instances of `T` as being equivalent *for its purposes* even when they are decidedly not the same, especially if some function, invoked on each, would yield the same value.  If the function in question regards `null` as a legitimate value, then a non-null value where the function returns the same value as it would with `null` should compare equal to `null`.